# Method context.Orders.RemoveRange raised InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Method context.Orders.RemoveRange raised InvalidOperationException. It called from multiple tasks. I tried to lock context.Orders.RemoveRange but the same exception was raised.

Exception is:

```
InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
```

This is the source code where an exception was raised

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private MyContext context;

    public Foo(MyContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task Update(Order order)
    {
        context.Orders.RemoveRange(context.Orders.Where(r => r.CustomerID == 100));
        context.Orders.RemoveRange(context.Orders.Where(r => r.CustomerID == 120));
        order.EmployeeID = 2;
        context.Update(order);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Exception stacktrace:

```
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.RemoveRange(IEnumerable`1 entities)
   at WebApplication2.Foo.Update(Order order) in D:\Projects\RemoveRangeIssue\WebApplication2\Foo.cs:line 24
```

I added the small project to GitHub to reproduce the issue above. Here is a [link](https://github.com/sabond9/RemoveRangeIssue). It has Task.WaitAll to run both method in two threads. 
How can I fix the issue with the method context.Orders.RemoveRange called from multiple tasks without removing Task.WaitAll?

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that the problem is not actually the code that you show here but instead it is this bit that you have used in the GitHub repo:

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => _foo.Update(order));
var task2 = Task.Run(() => _foo2.Update(order));
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
```

So here you effectively have two `Foo` implementations and you want to run a query on both in parallel. Since you are using dependency injection and they are both created in the same scope, they will also resolve *the same database context*.

Running concurrent queries in the same database context is generally not supported. Entity Framework database contexts use a single underlying database connection and you can only ever have one query run at the same time.

If you absolutely need to have these two queries run at the same time, then the solution is to use *separate* database contexts which each have their own database connection. To do this, you will need to create a new service scope and resolve the database context from there.

With Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, this would look like this:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public Foo(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public async Task Update(Order order)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyContext>();

            // this context is now separate from others
            // …
        }
    }
}
```

You would have to check with the Autofac documentation to see how that is done there.

Alternatively, you could also keep the `Foo` implementation the way it is and instead resolve `Foo` from within a new scope (which would then pull in the context from that same scope). This moves the service scope creation into the *caller* of `Foo` which might be a better thing to do depending on what `Foo`’s responsibility actually is.

```
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public ValuesController(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DoStuff()
    {
        var task1 = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var foo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IFoo>();
                await foo.Update();
            }
        });
        var task2 = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var foo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IFoo>();
                await foo.Update();
            }
        });

        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

---

> `context.Orders.Where(r => r.CustomerID == 100)`

This will just return an IQueryable that represents the query but was not yet executed. When you then implicitly iterate that queryable with `RemoveRange`, the query is then executed.

This is generally not a good idea with EntityFramework. You should always *explicitly* execute a query using `ToListAsync()` or `ToArrayAsync()`:

```
public async Task Update(Order order)
{
    var ordersToRemove = await context.Orders
        .Where(r => r.CustomerID == 100 || r.CustomerID == 120)
        .ToListAsync();
    context.Orders.RemoveRange(ordersToRemove);

    order.EmployeeID = 2;
    context.Update(order);

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by “Alternatively, you could also keep the Foo implementation the way it is and instead resolve Foo from within a new scope (which would then pull in the context from that same scope).”? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @MasterMedia I have added an example for that.